# Convert oracle Query (SYSDATE() BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE) to Solr query

Tags: oracle, solr, solrj

I need help in converting the following oracle query to Solr Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM urlconfigs_table 
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' AND SYSDATE() BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE

SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();

q.append("ACTIVE_FLAG:(Y)");
```

How to query in solr using currentdate and between startdate and edndate columns in solr collection.

Could you please help on this.

Comment: This query is invalid in Oracle. There must be no parentheses after `SYSDATE`. `SYSDATE` gets the current date/time down to seconds in Oracle. So the query gets all rows since start_date until the very first second of end_date (i.e. midnight), unless end_date is a misnomer and contains a time itself. The equivalent for `SYSDATE`in Solr should be `NOW`.

Comment: `ACTIVE_FLAG:Y AND START_DATE:[* TO NOW] AND END_DATE:[NOW TO *]`